# Mapping errors from Command::new("/bin/bash") arguments

Tags: rust

I am executing a bash command, for which I would like to catch an error when the move argument fails. Since there is one more command after move, my goal is to capture specifically whether the move operation got successfully executed to a status code and to break out of the entire Rust program.

Is there a way to accomplish this? I have provided below the source code.

```
let path : String = "/home/directory/".to_string();
let command = Command::new("bin/bash")
                  .arg("-c")
                  .arg("mv somefile1.txt /home/")
                  .arg("cp ~/somefile2.txt .")
                  .stdout(Stdio::piped())
                  .output();
```

Answer (score 1):

`bash -c` doesn't accept two commands like that. You could try splitting it into two separate `Command`s:

```
Command::new("bash")
    .arg("-c")
    .arg("mv somefile1.txt /home/")
    .status()?
    .success()             // bool
    .then(|| ())           // convert bool to Option
    .ok_or("mv failed")?;  // convert Option to Result

Command::new("bash")
    .arg("-c")
    .arg("cp ~/somefile2.txt .")
    .status()?
    .success()             // bool
    .then(|| ())           // convert bool to Option
    .ok_or("cp failed")?;  // convert Option to Result
```

Or joining them into a single command with `&&`:

```
Command::new("bash")
    .arg("-c")
    .arg("mv somefile1.txt /home/ && cp ~/somefile2.txt .")
    .status()?
    .success()             # bool
    .then(|| ())           # convert bool to Option
    .ok_or("failed")?;     # convert Option to Result
```

Better yet, use native Rust functions:

- `mv` → [`std::fs::rename`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.rename.html)
- `cp` → [`std::fs::copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.copy.html)
- `~` → [`home::home_dir`](https://docs.rs/home/latest/home/fn.home_dir.html)

This avoids the overhead of calling out to bash and is portable to non-Unix operating systems.

```
use std::fs;
use dirs::home_dir;

if let Some(home) = home_dir() {
    fs::rename("somefile1.txt", home.join("somefile1.txt"))?;
    fs::copy(home.join("somefile2.txt"), ".")?;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I will have to stick to bash as its a constraint.  I agree with splitting the commands up. But my question revolves more around the structure of the code that is required to be appended to Command::new() for catching the error when that particular command fails.

Comment: From [the docs for `std::fs::rename`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.rename.html) (emphasis mine): "On Unix, if `from` is a directory, `to` must also be an (empty) directory. **If `from` is not a directory, `to` must also be not a directory.**" I believe you have to append the filename to the homedir in order for this to work.